# Coffeescript for extending objects

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to do below in Coffeescript:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 13,
adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

I've tried something like below but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
    revision: 13
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
```

Is there something wrong with above code that creates below error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are defining `DS.Store`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can [see](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aApp.Store%20=%20DS.Store.extend%0A%20%20%20%20revision%3a%2013%0A%20%20%20%20adapter%3a%20DS.RESTAdapter.create%28%29), there is nothing wrong with your code. Seems like `DS.Store` is undefined. You also can try passing `-b` (`--bare`) to the compiler so it won't add the top-level function safety wrapper to your code.